# discord.py user embed title input only taking one word

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this command called `p!customembed [color] [title] [description]`. It's basically what it sounds like. However, there is one flaw. I want my bot to send a blue embed with the title being "potatoes are nice" and the description being "test". However, the title is "potatoes" and the description "are nice test". I was thinking of separating the title and description in the ctx command with something like `/`, like `p!customembed [color] [title] / [description]` to separate the two, but I have no clue how to do it. Can anyone help? Thx

```py
@client.command()
async def customembed(ctx, color: discord.Colour, title, *, description):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, color=color)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with replacing `color, title, *, description` with `content` and then split the content up (you would have to remake your command a bit).

Revised example:

Command:

```
p!customembed /color/title/description
```

Code:

```
@client.command()
async def customembed(ctx, content):
    color, title, description = content.split('/', 3)

    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, color=int(color))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: To make it simpler, you could also do `color, title, description = content.split('/', 3)` which will also work fine

Comment: Oh okay, didn't know that @Bagle